# Dynamically adding class using JavaScript in component does not update styles

Tags: svelte

When I add a class defined in the `<style>` section of a [Svelte component](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format) to an element at runtime via JavaScript, the CSS properties do not get applied although the class is indeed added. However, if the class is defined in another CSS file which is imported into the component, the code works. Why is this?

See the example below that reproduces this behavior:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  function addClass() {
    document.getElementById('example').classList.add('foo');
    // class is added, but nothing appears to happen
  }
</script>

<div id="example">Hi</div>
<button on:click={addClass}>Add foo class</button>

<style>
.foo {
  color : #be0000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS declared in the `<style>` element of a Svelte component are scoped to the component by default. To achieve this, Svelte adds an extra class to the selector, e.g. `svelte-buqcoz`, and also adds that class to all elements that match the selector in the component. Thus, simply adding the `bar` class at runtime is not sufficient to change the styles. In addition, in this case, Svelte sees that the `bar` class is not even used and thus does not generate any CSS for it.

You can use `:global` to make the class available everywhere, which will allow you to apply the class dynamically.

```css
:global(.bar) {
    color : #be0000;
}
```

See also: https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style